# position fixed stucks on mobile device with webkit overflow scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML in which header is fixed and only the body content should have elastic scroll. Now the problem is coming when you scroll towards up and wait until the scrollbar is hidden and try to scroll again it freezes scroll and won't let you scroll for few seconds. Or is there anyway without position:fixed I can make the div static. It is just coming on mobile iOS devices.

Please check the [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3sTbS5PHVwGNGVvZGpSbkxEcms/view?usp=sharing) as well.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sohail</title>
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                height: 100%;
                -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
                background-color: red;
            }
            div {
                overflow-y: scroll;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: green;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:fixed;width:100%">
            <div style="height: 20%;background-color: yellow;">
                Header
            </div>
            <div>
                Sohail Hussain<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                ABCDEFGHI
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're applying the `overflow-y :scroll;` on every div, that can't be right? Use classes for different divs.

Comment: Yeah you can just avoid it, but the actual problem is div gets stucked on scroll.Check the behavior in the video.

Answer (score 0):

Sohail, use this code. I am sure it will fix the problem:

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.scrollDivWrap {
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%; 
}
.scrollDiv {
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
header {
    height: 50px; 
    background-color: yellow;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sohail</title>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        Header
    </header>
    <div class="scrollDivWrap">
     <div class="scrollDiv">
            Sohail Hussain<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            FDSFSDFDSFS<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
            ABCDEFGHI
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```